# Date not showing in date input field laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, date

While I retrieve data from database, I have a column named 'deadline' it do not displaying in my blade date input field. date input format is 'mm/dd/yyyy'. I tried to format as it is but it do not work.
Here is my code for blade file `<input type="date" class="form-control @error('deadline') is-invalid @enderror" name="deadline" value="{{ date('m/d/Y', strtotime($job->deadline)) }}">`

I have inspected this field and it shows value correctly but do not appear on by for input
[image: I inspect this field and it shows value correctly but do not appear on by for input]

Here is my output screenshot
[image: Here is my output screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Value) reference:

> One thing to note is that the displayed date format differs from the
>   actual value — the displayed date format will be chosen based on the
>   set locale of the user's browser, whereas the date value is always
>   formatted yyyy-mm-dd

You should set value property in `yyyy-mm-dd` format. The output formatting will be based on the user's browser locale. ie, you may not be able to customize `<input type="date">` output format.

```html
<input type="date" name="bday" value="2019-09-23">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

value="{{ date('m-d-Y', strtotime($job->deadline)) }}"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

value="{{\Illuminate\Support\Carbon::parse($quote->date_quote)->format("Y-m-d")}}" type="date you should make sure that the value you write is that format (2023-12-30)